# count the number of occurances of .dll in a file

Tags: unix, shell

say I have a file in on a unix server, I want to count the number of occurances of .dll or say .exe in the file.

how can I do this?

Comment: Strange question. Are you looking for a simple character search or actual dependence list of what .dll's your .exe calls. I was not aware that .exes run on unix and call .dlls. Of couse a windows system can access a unix drive share and load .exes from it. Pls clarify

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try (assuming that it's a text file):

```
grep -o '.dll' filename | wc -l
```

If it's a binary file, try:

```
grep -binary-files=text -o '.dll' filename | wc -l
```

Or

```
strings filename | grep -o '.dll' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do <strike>`grep -c .dll <file>`</strike> (as dennis said) `grep -o <file> | wc -l` just change '.dll' to whatever you feel like searching for.

Comment: That doesn't take into consideration the possibility of the string appearing twice on a line.

Comment: Your right ... that'll teach me to post while trying to listen to s conference call.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
perl -lne '$c++while/[.]dll/g;END{print$c}' <filename
```

You can modify the regular expression (`/[.]dll/`) in the middle to search for something else (see `man perlre` for details). If you want to search for something containing a newline, add `-0777` after `perl`.